# Issue with my Ajax & JQuery using Spring MVC in java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

My jQuery AJAX implementation does not work properly, so if i want add, delete, update a product, or retrieve all sites, it simply does not react to my clicks.

Here is my simple web-page that allows me to click but i donot get any result. 
[image: My simple we page that allows me to click but i donot get any result out of my clicks]

> When someone wants to submit the form with the specified ID, all form fields are assigned to appropriate variables. After that, a new JSON document is generated based on the form field variables. Then the AJAX call is performed. It is directed to URL which is specified in the action attribute of form tag. The JSON is used as a data which needs to be processed.

[You can downlaod my project from here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByjbQDEh-nyvY3M5X0FsRXJvOUE)

**I get there errors:**

```
localhost:8080/api/sites Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
2localhost:8080/api/sites/ Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

From my Java class:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/api/sites")
        public List<Site> getAllSites(){
            return siteService.getAllSites();
        }
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/sites")
    public void addSite(@RequestBody Site site){
        siteService.addSite(site);
    }
```

A webpage to replicate the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <hr><p>  New page </p>
           <input name="search" type="text" maxlength="100" id="search"/>

       <button onclick="getAllSites()"> Show All </button>
           <hr>
           <hr>

    <p> Id: <input name="search" type="text" maxlength="100" id="id"/></p>
    <p> First name: <input name="search" type="text" maxlength="100" id="name"/></p>

    <button onclick="addSite()"> Save </button>

    <div id="site"></div>
    <script>
        function addSite()
        { var data = {
                id: document.getElementById("id").value,
                name: document.getElementById("name").value

            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/api/sites", 
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data)
            });
        }           
function getAllSites()
    {
        $("#site").html("");

        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/sites/",  function(data)
        {
            for (var i in data) {
                $('#site').append("<p>ID: " + data[i].id + "</p>")
                $('#site').append("<p>Name: " + data[i].name + "</p>")

            }
        });
    }       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, 'it doesn't work' is not enough information for us to help you. Could you please check the console after clicking the button to make the AJAX request and tell us what, if any, errors you see

Comment: @Mina I've got a doubt you have mapping for an url something like this: `http://localhost:8080/api/sites123`. Are you sure it is what you intented to have?

Comment: The idea of my project is taht i have a seperate webpage that can be placed anywhere. Its not included in my java project.

Comment: Can you please provide the script errors you see in browser console?

Comment: @Mina from the source code I see you define the following mapping: `value = "/api/sites/{id}"`. but in javascript you lack `/` symbol before id. try it. also, do not forget to use `@` to mention specific person on the site

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich value = "/api/sites/{id}" comes with getOneSite

Comment: @Mina but here you call it without `/`: `$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/sites" + id,  function(data)`

Comment: @Mina Actually your project works fine. I just imported and works ok.  Where are you trying to open web page, from url like localhost:8080/mySites.html or like a file:///your-disk/mysites.html?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the ajax implementation is in a file for example: mySites.html and you need to test it directly from browser or from other site try this:

1. Go to SiteController.class
2. If you need to test your api outside of your localhost:8080 then add `@CrossOrigin` annotation to the specific method of SiteController.class, for example in this case I'm enabling CrossOrigin for two specific methods:

Method 1

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/api/sites")
public List<Site> getAllSites(){
    return siteService.getAllSites();
}
```

Method 2

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/sites")
public void addSite(@RequestBody Site site){
    siteService.addSite(site);
}
```

For more information about @CrossOrigin see the following documentation from spring site [@CrossOrigin Document](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

My conclusion of this answer is because the first time that I ran the ajax implementation I got the  `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` exception from console developer, wich means that for security reasons the browser block the ajax request when it is outside of the rest api host.

All the rest of the components (backend java classes, spring) worked perfect after I get imported to my development environment.

Comment: I use  file:///your-disk/mysites.html . Did you use my or your html? if yours could provide that with the answer becuase mine until now does not show any result :(

Comment: I use exactly the same html that you post, it works fine, just need to add the @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") annotations to the methods of SiteController, restart tomcat and try again.

Comment: Also try this: in chrome browser go to Developer Console, in the console tab you should see the javascript errors and then share it to verify any error.

Comment: I tried what you said i get the error above (check my post) Could you reupload the projrct after your fixs as zipfile ?

Comment: localhost:8080/api/sites Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
2localhost:8080/api/sites/ Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED means that your html page can't connect to the localhost server, maybe the spring app is not running, try this: open a tab in your browser and write: http://localhost:8080/api/sites and send the output that you see from browser.  In wich port is running your api/sites? 8080?